# вопрос реализации алгоритма определения точного времени

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм

от некого **api** получаю текущее время в формате - `1589468357`.

экспериментальным путем я понял, что это число секунд если считать с 1970 года..

вопрос:

> как максимально не затратно определять точное время зная это число

думал сначала ввести некую *константу*, которая явлала бы собой число секунд с начала 2020 года, и от полученного числа онтимать эту *константу* и дальше делить результат, но придется учитывать високосные года и тд, а мне не кайф)

также думал искать число секунд для начала *текущего дня*, но понял, что число также может являть дату раньше, чем *текущий день*..

есть какие идеи?

Comment: Посмотрите тут: https://pythonru.com/osnovy/modul-time-v-python  Ваше значение - то, что возвращает `time()`.

Comment: @Harry ловлю дикий фэйспалм, спасибо! опубликуйте в качестве ответа чтоли..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваше число - это значение, которое возвращает стандартная функция `time()` (число секунд, прошедших "с начала эпохи" - после 1 января 1970, 00:00:00).

Для работы с ним можно воспользоваться не менее стандартными функциями модуля `time`, прочесть о которых можно, например, [здесь](https://pythonru.com/osnovy/modul-time-v-python).

Answer (score -2):

```
from datetime import datetime
a = datetime.now().date()
print(a)
```

Comment: и что это даст?